# Change font size of the name parameter for res

Tags: fonts, cv, resume

I'm currently creating  a resume using the res class. Is there a way for me to change the font size of the name parameter (which appears at the top of the page for me)? It's not quite like a section header because it's automatically there.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). It speeds up the process in terms of getting useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`res` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/res) provides `\namefont` which you can redefine to suit your needs. Default is `\large\bfseries`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\bfseries\LARGE}
\begin{document}

\name{A Person}
\opening
\end{document}
```

I'd avoid using the `res` class, and settle for something more recent, like [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv), or create your resume manually.